# Letters within integers. What are they?

Tags: java, types, double, int, literals

This is an excerpt of code from a class I am working with in Java (below). Obviously the code is defining a static variable named EPSILON with the data type double. What I don't understand is the "1E-14" part. What kind of number is that? What does it mean?

final double EPSILON = 1E-14;

Comment: Good question. I've never come across this in all these years. I new about F, D, and L ( ie float f = 1F; double d = 1D; long l = 1L; )

Comment: @CarsonMyers Isn't an answer like yours not one that helps no one and the only effect it can have is that people feel bad and therefore shouldn't be given as an answer?
And therefore: Isn't your answer something that doesn't belong in this forum?

Comment: @fose yes, it was - I've deleted it, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your case, this is equivalent to writing:

```
final double EPSILON = 0.00000000000001;
```

except you don't have to count the zeros. This is called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and is helpful when writing very large or very small numbers.

Answer (score 9):

The "E" notation is scientific notation. You'll see it on calculators too. It means "one times (ten to the power of -14)".

For another example, 2E+6 == 2,000,000.

Answer (score 8):

1E3 => 1000

1E-1 => 0.1

1E-2 => 0.01

It's a way for writing 1 * 10<sup>-14</sup>

Answer (score 4):

That's [Exponential notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_notation#E_notation)

Answer (score 2):

1E-14 is 1 times 10 to the power of -14

Comment: I think you mean 10, 1 to the -14 = 1